# How to refresh page in Jquery Ajax form submission before success?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am submitting a form and setting user object in request at server side. After that I want my page to be refreshed before success method of jquery ajax so that the updated values can be reflected. Could somebody help me?
Below is my jquery code :

```
   function viewMemberProfile(userId){

         document.getElementById("memberId").value=userId;

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url:'viewMemberProfile.html',
             cache: false,
             data: $("#memberProfileForm").serialize(),

             success: function (data) {
                   $("#memberProfileDiv").reveal({ 
                         animation : 'fade',
                         animationspeed : 400, 
                         closeonbackgroundclick : true,
                         dismissmodalclass : 'close' 
                   });
             }
    });

    return false;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of perform an ajax request and then reload the whole page? you're forcing your user to a double http request. Instead, I suggest you to write a `updateUserProfileDiv()` function that does all the changes you need. It would be used like:

```
function viewMemberProfile(userId){

    document.getElementById("memberId").value=userId;

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url:'viewMemberProfile.html',
       cache: false,
       data: $("#memberProfileForm").serialize(),

       success: function (data) {

          //write new data to the profile panel
          updateUserProfileDiv($("#memberProfileForm").serialize());

          $("#memberProfileDiv").reveal({ 
             animation : 'fade',
             animationspeed : 400, 
             closeonbackgroundclick : true,
             dismissmodalclass : 'close' 
          });
      }
    });

    return false;

 }
```

For example (I don't know your data):

```
function updateUserProfileDiv(data){
    $('#username').html(data.username);
    $('#birth').html(data.date_of_birth);
    $('#city').html(data.city);

}
```

Comment: I this case I would need to return User object from Server side controller method. Right ?

Comment: could you please check whether below code is right or not to return User object ?

Comment: You have user's data **already** in the form (that's what you send to server). If those value are enough, no need to fetch any data from server (that's the example I show you). If user value can change on server (maybe after saving), then yes you need data from server.

Comment: ~
 
@RequestMapping(value = "viewMemberProfile") public @ResponseBody User viewMemberProfile(@RequestParam("memberId") String userId,ModelMap map, HttpSession session) { User activeUser = null; List<User> userList = null; Integer uId = Integer.valueOf(userId); User memberProfile = null; try { userList = (List<User>) session.getAttribute("userList"); for (User user : userList) { if (user.getId() == uId) { memberProfile = user; break; } } } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } return memberProfile; ~

Comment: Now I get it: it's Java. I'm not a Java expert, but I think it works as long as User is a serializable class. Also, it should serialize to JSON.

Answer (score -1):

```
success: function (data) {
location.reload();
}
```

use this to refresh the page

Comment: I tried with this already. its not opening dialog box if I put this line.

Comment: if you are using struts2 then i think you should go for struts2 form,it would be really easy to populate struts2 form.